# How to automatically insert a smallskip after a theorem

Tags: theorems

How can I automatically insert a `\smallskip` after a theorem/lemma? I.e.:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
    Some Lemma
\end{lemma}
\smallskip % this automatically
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a small but complete example, using `\documentclass`, etc.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I added it

Comment: It would only help if you added some text after the `\smallskip`, so that people could see in the output what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the manual `\smallskip` and added these two lines:

```
\let\svendlemma\endlemma
\def\endlemma{\svendlemma\smallskip}
```

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\let\svendlemma\endlemma
\def\endlemma{\svendlemma\smallskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
    Some Lemma
\end{lemma}
%\smallskip % this automatically
xxx
\end{document}
```

Comment: how would the same work for definitions?

Comment: @Descrates As before, `\let\svenddefinition\enddefinition
\def\enddefinition{\svenddefinition\smallskip}`.  However, note that these fixes will not work with the star `*` versions of the environment.

Comment: thanks, I thought that it would work like this but my document was corrupted. Now everything works fine!

Answer (score 4):

A first approach using `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \apptocmd{\endlemma}{\smallskip}{}{}
```

A second one using `thmtools` and `spacebelow` key:

```
\usepackage{thmtools}
  \declaretheoremstyle[
    numberwithin=section,
    spacebelow=12pt,
    spaceabove=12pt,
    bodyfont=\itshape]{mystyle}
  \declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{Lemma}
```

Here is a MWE with both with both approaches:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsthm}
  \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \apptocmd{\endlemma}{\smallskip}{}{}

\usepackage{thmtools}
  \declaretheoremstyle[
    numberwithin=section,
    spacebelow=12pt,
    spaceabove=12pt,
    bodyfont=\itshape]{mystyle}
  \declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{Lemma}
  \declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{First solution}

\begin{lemma}
    Some Lemma
\end{lemma}

Hello world!

\begin{lemma}
    Some Lemma
\end{lemma}

Hello world!

\section{Second solution}

\begin{Lemma}
    Some Lemma
\end{Lemma}

Hello world!

\begin{Lemma}
    Some Lemma
\end{Lemma}

Hello world!

\end{document}
```

[image]